How should we handle undeletion/reopen requests for previously deleted/closed "trivia" questions that are now on-topic?
Recent community consensus have made both "trivia" and identification questions on-topic. How should we approach undeletion/reopen requests for such previously closed and deleted posts?
I recently encountered a situation that highlights this issue. On 2024-10-10, I flagged one of my deleted questions, "Who covered The Cure's 'Boys Don't Cry' in the film 'Boys Don't Cry'?",  with a custom flag for undeletion and reopening. (Note: This question wasn't part of the 2018 ID questions purge.)

I'm requesting that this question be undeleted and reopened. The community has changed its stance on "trivia" questions, and the "trivia" close reason no longer applies. Similarly, ID questions are now considered on-topic.

This question was originally closed and deleted as "trivia," which was off-topic at the time. However, in 2022, the community consensus changed to not close questions for being "trivia". Moreover, it's also an identification question, which became on-topic again in 2024 after being made off-topic in 2018.
Given these changes in community stance, I used a custom flag to request undeletion and reopening. To my surprise, the flag was declined with this message:

Declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

This response left me puzzled. What standard flag would be appropriate for this situation? There's no undelete review queue, so even if I voted to undelete (as a 10K rep user), other users wouldn't know to review it. And what about users with less than 10K rep? What options do they have?
Adding to my confusion, the question was eventually undeleted and reopened anyway. This mirrors a previous experience where I flagged outdated comments that were declined but ended up getting removed anyway.
Interestingly, I made a similar request in August for another question, which was marked "helpful," and the post was subsequently undeleted and reopened: Animation featuring DC's Adam Strange saving planet Rann from a solar-powered war machine (This question also wasn't part of the 2018 ID questions purge.)
To avoid wasting both the flaggers' time and that of the reviewing moderators, I'd appreciate some clarity on the policy for flagging these previously off-topic, now on-topic closed and deleted posts. Should we continue to flag them, or is there a better approach? Would it be more appropriate to bring these cases up on meta?
Could the moderator team provide some guidance on the best way to handle these undeletion requests?

I actually wonder how you are encountering those deleted questions that aren't yours. For a user with privileges received at reputation points of yours, you don't really encounter a deleted question.

@AJ I followed/bookmarked them.

@AJ - You can also Google for them

@AJ I'm curious why you're asking about how I find deleted questions. Like other users, I simply bookmark or follow posts I've seen before they were deleted. Are you hinting at some way to search for deleted questions other than your own on the site? If so, that would be incredibly useful for undeleting and reopening trivia and ID questions that are now on-topic.

@Valorum While Google can show closed questions, it doesn't display results for deleted questions. AJ was curious about how I'm encountering questions that have been deleted.

I'd suggest you keep patience till all valid ID questions get undeleted/reopened by CMs instead of flagging every other question for undeletion. I will be rejecting those flags.
For trivia questions, I'd suggest the same. Please avoid pushing every trivia question that was closed before the trivia close reason was retired to the reopen queue.

Hold on, I think I'm missing something. The community decided trivia questions are on-topic now, right? It sounds like you're not planning to reopen the old closed trivia questions, and you'll decline flags about them. I get waiting for CMs on the ID questions, but what about all those trivia questions? Are we just leaving those closed indefinitely, even though the community agreed they're on-topic back in 2022?

I said declining flags about ID questions.

The question I mentioned in my post was closed as trivia before the 2018 ID question ban.

“Please avoid pushing every trivia question that was closed before the trivia close reason was retired to the reopen queue.” - why?

I'm trying to understand the inconsistency here. The community and one of the moderators have undeleted and reopened several trivia and ID questions before. Why was this particular flag declined? I thought moderators were supposed to help with this process—wouldn't that speed things up? What am I missing?

There is a limit to how many deleted questions that are viewable by people.  I personally don't have an issue with undeleting and opening a few questions.  Please be aware that re-opening a lot of questions pushes new content down the main page, so please be aware of that too.
